# MacTeX problem: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex does not exist error

Tags: installing, mactex, texshop, mac, bibdesk

Like others have noted, after upgrading to El Capitan, there was a required reconfiguration for `MacTeX`. I completed the fix specified here: https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf. So, I changed the Path settings for (pdf)TeX from `/usr/texbin` to `/Library/TeX/texbin` in `TeXShop` preferences, and I changed `/usr/texbin/pdflatex` to `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex` and `/usr/texbin/xelatex` to `/Library/TeX/ texbin/xelatex`, in `BibDesk` preferences.

However, if I try to compile a document, I still get the following error report:

`/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex does not exist. TeXShop is a front end for TeX, but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a distribution was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to http://tug.org/MacTeX and follow the instructions to (re)install MacTeX. A less likely possibility is that a tool path is incorrectly configured in TeXShop preferences. This can happen if you are using the macports or fink distributions`

I’m now not sure if I should really re-install, or am I missing some bit of the fix.

I also tried going to terminal and doing `which pdftex`, but it returned nothing. Reinstall?

Comment: Did you have a previous install of MacTeX or BasicTeX 2015? Check the output of `ls -l /usr/local/texlive` in Terminal to see if TL 2015 is installed; if not, you'll have to install it or follow the instructions for TL 2014 and earlier in Herb's UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf document.

Comment: `ls -l /usr/local/texlive` returns: `total 0
drwxr-xr-x  20 root  wheel  680 Oct 20  2014 2013`. So, is the best thing to do just go ahead an install MacTeX?

Comment: If that directory is empty, I recommend that you install MacTeX 2015, as you've already configured the GUI applications for it.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell Well it is obviously not empty, is it? The comment gives a directory listing. Nonetheless, updating to 2015 is surely to be recommended in this case. No need to delete the old versions - they can happily coexist. (They will also probably work once 2015 is installed and you can switch back using the preference pane if necessary.)

Comment: @cfr I missed the 2013, because of the way the lines wrapped in the comment. Still, no TL 2015, which is expected by OP's symlinking setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a similar problem. I manually found where the executables lived, turns out on my system the path was: `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin/`. then in one of the shell initialization scripts on my system (specifically `~/.zlogin`, but it could `~/.zshrc` or other) i added this path to my `$PATH`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin/:$PATH"
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem after installing El Capitan.

Did you test if you are able to use pdflatex running from the terminal?
In my case it worked.

After knowing that I used `which pdflatex` to see where the pdflatex is, andthe result was `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`.
Then I went to this directory, and I noticed that most of its content (including the pdflatex) are actually links to other things, and in the case of pdflatex it is on the path: `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/`.

I changed the path settings in TeXShop to this directory and it solved the problem for me.

Comment: Perfect answer! Solved my issue within a few seconds after googeling round about 30 minutes :-)